# UITextView fix width in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitextview, xcode8

Can you, please, help me with my UITextView that changes it's width while pinching. What I want is to simply scale UITextView up and down with words staying on their lines.

[image]

Some of the code is below.

Text View Did Change function:

```
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Pinch function:

```
func handlePinch(pinchGesture recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view as? UITextView {
        let pinchScale: CGFloat = recognizer.scale
        view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: pinchScale, y: pinchScale)
        recognizer.scale = 1.0

        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Try scaling the leading and trailing constraints instead of the view frame

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: How about increasing font size with the pinch?